# Model is not been training when tf.Session() is used

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, generative-adversarial-network

I am new to TensorFlow and Keras. I am trying to understand GANs using TF 1.x (using this repo https://github.com/hse-aml) and I have trouble with the below function which has been used to create a session. My problem is what exactly this function is doing (why can not we use tf.Session() alone). When I use tf.Session(), the model was not been training.

```
from keras import backend as K

def weird_session():
    curr_session = tf.get_default_session()
    if curr_session is not None:
        curr_session.close()
    K.clear_session()
    config = tf.ConfigProto()
    config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
    s = tf.InteractiveSession(config=config)
    K.set_session(s)
    return s
s=weird_session()
```

This is the full code I have used.

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras import layers as L
import numpy as np


IMG_SHAPE=(36,36,3)
####################################################################################### DOWNLOAD DATASET
!git clone https://github.com/RaviSoji/colab_utils.git  # Include the "!".
import colab_utils
drive = colab_utils.get_gdrive()
colab_utils.pull_from_gdrive(drive, 'GAN/my.npy','hah.npy')
dataset=np.load('hah.npy')
plt.imshow(dataset[0])

data = np.float32(dataset)/255.
########################################################################################

from keras import backend as K

####################################################  weird_session() function -the problem
def weird_session():
    curr_session = tf.get_default_session()
    if curr_session is not None:
        curr_session.close()
    K.clear_session()
    config = tf.ConfigProto()
    config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
    s = tf.InteractiveSession(config=config)
    K.set_session(s)
    return s
##################################################
s=weird_session()


IMG_SHAPE = data.shape[1:]

CODE_SIZE = 256

generator = Sequential()
generator.add(L.InputLayer([CODE_SIZE],name='noise'))
generator.add(L.Dense(10*8*8, activation='elu'))
generator.add(L.Reshape((8,8,10)))
generator.add(L.Conv2DTranspose(64,kernel_size=(5,5),activation='elu'))
generator.add(L.Conv2DTranspose(64,kernel_size=(5,5),activation='elu'))
generator.add(L.UpSampling2D(size=(2,2)))
generator.add(L.Conv2DTranspose(32,kernel_size=3,activation='elu'))
generator.add(L.Conv2DTranspose(32,kernel_size=3,activation='elu'))
generator.add(L.Conv2DTranspose(32,kernel_size=3,activation='elu'))
generator.add(L.Conv2D(3,kernel_size=3,activation=None))

discriminator = Sequential()
discriminator.add(L.InputLayer(IMG_SHAPE))
discriminator.add(L.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=1))
discriminator.add(L.LeakyReLU(0.12))
discriminator.add(L.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=1))
discriminator.add(L.LeakyReLU(0.12))
discriminator.add(L.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
discriminator.add(L.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=1))
discriminator.add(L.LeakyReLU(0.12))
discriminator.add(L.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=1))
discriminator.add(L.LeakyReLU(0.12))
discriminator.add(L.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2))) 
discriminator.add(L.Flatten())
discriminator.add(L.Dense(256,activation='tanh'))
discriminator.add(L.Dense(2,activation=tf.nn.log_softmax))


noise = tf.placeholder('float32',[None,CODE_SIZE])
real_data = tf.placeholder('float32',[None,]+list(IMG_SHAPE))
logp_real = discriminator(real_data)
generated_data = generator(noise)
logp_gen = discriminator(generated_data)

d_loss = -tf.reduce_mean(logp_real[:,1] + logp_gen[:,0])
d_loss += tf.reduce_mean(discriminator.layers[-1].kernel**2)
disc_optimizer =  tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1e-3).minimize(d_loss,var_list=discriminator.trainable_weights)

g_loss = -tf.reduce_mean(logp_gen[:,1])
gen_optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(g_loss,var_list=generator.trainable_weights)

s.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())


def sample_noise_batch(bsize):
    return np.random.normal(size=(bsize, CODE_SIZE)).astype('float32')

def sample_data_batch(bsize):
    idxs = np.random.choice(np.arange(data.shape[0]), size=bsize)
    return data[idxs]

def sample_images(nrow,ncol, sharp=False):
    images = generator.predict(sample_noise_batch(bsize=nrow*ncol))
    if np.var(images)!=0:
        images = images.clip(np.min(data),np.max(data))
    for i in range(nrow*ncol):
        plt.subplot(nrow,ncol,i+1)
        if sharp:
            plt.imshow(images[i].reshape(IMG_SHAPE),cmap="gray", interpolation="none")
        else:
            plt.imshow(images[i].reshape(IMG_SHAPE),cmap="gray")
    plt.show()

def sample_probas(bsize):
    plt.title('Generated vs real data')
    plt.hist(np.exp(discriminator.predict(sample_data_batch(bsize)))[:,1],
             label='D(x)', alpha=0.5,range=[0,1])
    plt.hist(np.exp(discriminator.predict(generator.predict(sample_noise_batch(bsize))))[:,1],
             label='D(G(z))',alpha=0.5,range=[0,1])
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.show()

from IPython import display

for epoch in range(50000):
    feed_dict = {
        real_data:sample_data_batch(100),
        noise:sample_noise_batch(100)
    }

    for i in range(5):
        s.run(disc_optimizer,feed_dict)
    s.run(gen_optimizer,feed_dict)

    if epoch %100==0:
        display.clear_output(wait=True)
        sample_images(2,3,True)
```

Comment: Can you provide how you are training the model?

Comment: I have put the full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/InteractiveSession)

The only difference between `Session` and an `InteractiveSession` is that `InteractiveSession` makes itself the default session so that you can call `run()` or `eval()` without explicitly calling the session.

This can be helpful if you experiment with TF in python shell or in Jupyter notebooks, because it avoids having to pass an explicit Session object to run operations.

So if you use just `tf.Session` you would need to make it the default session as well.